# How can I get parent menu title name when I visit its child menu page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need a wordpress solution.
How can I get Parent Menu Title name when I visit its child page.
Suppose i have Parent 1
---child 1
---child 2
Now I'm on child 2 page. But I need its parent menu title.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be using breadcrumbs which easily can be added using a plugin. If you only want to display the parent menu title you can either try the plugin settings or hiding all other breadcrumbs using display:none; in your stylesheet. If you are not happy with the breadcrumbs styling, you can also override this in your stylesheet.